# List from list of assigned values

Tags: excel, list, match, lookup, vlookup

I have a list with assigned values that looks like this:

```
Name         Table
John Smith      1
Peter Doe       1
Andrew Rice     2
Leah Thomas     2
Ned Hartzal     3
Fred Thompson   1
```

and want to transfer this information to a list of each group/table like so:

```
1              2            3            
John Smith     Andrew Rice  Ned Hartzal
Peter Doe      Leah Thomas
Fred Thompson
```

I'm guessing it's some combination of LOOKUP and MATCH functions, but can't figure it out. I've searched several times and can't find an answer.

Could someone help?

Comment: =LOOKUP(J$2,$C$4:$C$98,$A$4:$A$98) and then dragged down, but I want to list all of the unique values in the group. Again, sorry, I'm new here and am just trying to figure this out.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sort in Table order, Smallest to Largest. Drag and drop to suit, delete Table column and relabel columns.